# Display mvc html table with edit button and data as label while display and data as textbox during edit mode

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, html-table

I want to display html table with edit button and table data as label and when ‘Edit’ button is clicked table row should display data in text box as below image

**table data with label (Normal display):**

[image]

**table data with textbox (display on click of Edit button):**

[image: table data with textbox (display on click of Edit button)]

**Full Page View:**

[image]

Having below issues:

1. Is there way to display table data as label/textbox respectively without playing with show/hide control as it need to duplicate each row data. In my code I used jQuery to show and hide controls accordingly which I don’t want to do.
2. Since my view is binded with two model, ViewModel(PurchaseComplete) concept is used , one is PurchaseModel and another is List< PurchaseModel > and how to send data from table edit row to the controller via POST method like normal form submit. In my code, UpdatePurchase(PurchaseComplete data) method received null and UpdatePurchase(int id, string gstNum, string distName,...) method received the binded data and not the edited data.

**PurchaseComplete.cs**

```
public class PurchaseComplete
{
    public PurchaseModel purchase { get; set; }
    public List<PurchaseModel> purchases { get; set; }
}
```

**PurchaseModel.cs**

```
public class PurchaseModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("GST Number")]
    public string GSTNumber { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Distributor Name")]
    public string DistributorName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Invoice Date")]
    public DateTime? InvoiceDate { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Invoice Number")]
    public string InvoiceNumber { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Purchase Amount")]
    public double? Total { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }

}
```

**HomeController.cs**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    AEEntities aEEntities;

    private List<Models.PurchaseModel> GetAllPurchaseDetails()
    {
        List<Models.PurchaseModel> modelObjPurchase = new List<Models.PurchaseModel>();
        List<Purchase> lstPurchase = aEEntities.Purchases.ToList();
        foreach (var item in lstPurchase)
        {
            modelObjPurchase.Add(new Models.PurchaseModel { Id = item.Id, GSTNumber = item.GSTNumber, DistributorName = item.DistributorName, InvoiceDate = item.InvoiceDate, InvoiceNumber = item.InvoiceNumber, Total = item.Total });
        }
        return modelObjPurchase;
    }
    public ActionResult Purchase()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your Purchase page.";

        PurchaseComplete purchaseCompleteObj = new PurchaseComplete();
        purchaseCompleteObj.purchases = GetAllPurchaseDetails();
        return View(purchaseCompleteObj);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Purchase(PurchaseComplete purchaseComplete)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //Database store operation
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Purchase");
    }


 //data received is null on click of update if sent as object
    public ActionResult UpdatePurchase(PurchaseComplete data)
    {
        if (data != null)
        {
            Purchase itemToUpdate = aEEntities.Purchases.ToList().FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id == data.Id);
            if (itemToUpdate != null)
            {
                //Database operation to delete
            }
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Purchase");
    }

 //data received is not having the update value instead it has only binded data if sent as separate item
    public ActionResult UpdatePurchase(int id, string gstNum, string distName, string invoDate, string invoNum, string total)
    {
        Purchase itemToUpdate = aEEntities.Purchases.ToList().FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id == id);
        if (itemToUpdate != null)
        {
            //DB store operation
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Purchase");
    }
  }
```

**Purchase.cshtml**

```
@model AEWebSite.Models.PurchaseComplete

@{
   ViewBag.Title = "View";
 }

 @using (Html.BeginForm())
 {
  @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

  <div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Purchase</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.purchase.GSTNumber, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.purchase.GSTNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.purchase.GSTNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.purchase.DistributorName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.purchase.DistributorName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.purchase.DistributorName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.purchase.InvoiceDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control- 
      label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.purchase.InvoiceDate, new{ htmlAttributes=new{ @class     = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.purchase.InvoiceDate, "", new { @class = "text- 
      danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.purchase.InvoiceNumber, htmlAttributes: new { @class = 
     "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.purchase.InvoiceNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.purchase.InvoiceNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.purchase.Total, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.purchase.Total, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.purchase.Total, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create Purchase" class="btn btn-outline-primary" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<table class="table table-dark table-hover" id="myDataTable" style="border-radius:20px;">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.purchase.GSTNumber)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.purchase.DistributorName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.purchase.InvoiceDate)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.purchase.InvoiceNumber)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.purchase.Total)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model.purchases)
    {
        <tr>
            <td class="txtcell cgst">
                @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.GSTNumber,
new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", style = "max-width:150px" } })
            </td>
            <td class="lblcell">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.GSTNumber)
            </td>
            <td class="txtcell cdistName">
                @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.DistributorName,
new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", style = "max-width:150px" } })
            </td>
            <td class="lblcell">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DistributorName)
            </td>
            <td class="txtcell cinvoDate">
                @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.InvoiceDate,
new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", style = "max-width:150px" } })
            </td>
            <td class="lblcell">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.InvoiceDate)
            </td>
            <td class="txtcell cinvoNumber">
                @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.InvoiceNumber,
new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", style = "max-width:150px" } })
            </td>
            <td class="lblcell">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.InvoiceNumber)
            </td>
            <td class="txtcell ctotal">
                @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.Total,
new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", style = "max-width:150px" } })
            </td>
            <td class="lblcell">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Total)
            </td>
            <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "UpdatePurchase", "Home", new { data = item }, new { @class = "btnModify" }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "UpdatePurchase", "Home", new { id = item.Id, gstNum = item.GSTNumber, distName = item.DistributorName, invoDate = item.InvoiceDate, invoNum = item.InvoiceNumber, total = item.Total }, new { @class = "btnModify" }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeletePurchase", new { id = item.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-secondary btn-sm" })

        </td>
         </tr>
      }

    </table>
   }
   <script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.txtcell').css('display', 'none');
    $('a[class*=btnModify]').click(function (e) {
        if ($(this).html() == "Edit") {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).html("Update");
            var categorydivs = $(this).closest('td').siblings();
            $.each(categorydivs, function (index, div) {
                if ($(this).hasClass("lblcell")) {
                    $(this).css('display', 'none');
                }
                else if ($(this).hasClass("txtcell")) {
                    $(this).css('display', 'table-cell');
                }
            });
        }
        else if ($(this).html() == "Update") {

            $(this).html("Edit");
            var categorydivs = $(this).closest('td').siblings();
            $.each(categorydivs, function (index, div) {
                if ($(this).hasClass("lblcell")) {
                    $(this).css('display', 'table-cell');
                }
                else if ($(this).hasClass("txtcell")) {
                    $(this).css('display', 'none');
                }
            });
        }
    });
  });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you can use ajax load for this.